# Can you share your experience about UAT tool to enter issues from users?

Tags: user-acceptance-testing

During UAT, which tool you are using so users can enter bugs/issues easily and you can focus to work with the dev. to resolve them faster for users. Please share what worked and what did not work.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In our process, users of production system do not enter bugs: they enter feedback.

It is shared responsibility (developers, QA, problem matter experts, analysts, sys admins etc) to triage the feedback and respond, which might be of several different types:

- more training and/or contact by field rep
- configuration changes not available to customers (performed by configuration/implementation team),
- configuration changes we ask our providers to do (and customers pay us for knowing what to change, when and how, and often do it for them),
- existing known bugs (higher feedback  might increase priority),
- new bugs.

For UAT (I assume User Acceptance testing - when asking a question, it is always helpful not to use jargon which might be misunderstood): We do not enter the feedback, but negotiate directly what is correct response (from above).

You cannot expect a all your users to have insight into all this process and enter bugs correctly, and even if users have direct access to bug tracker, someone still needs to evaluate new entries and triage them.